# String Encoding Algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm

```
Is there is a way to reduce the length of a string
using String encoding algorithm.
```

Unfortunately "Huffman coding" is not a solution for my case. I am searching for a coding algorithm which takes a string and generate a **string** which is shorter than the original string(input).

Comment: You can base64 encode the data produced by Huffman coding. Not sure whether it is shorter, but it will produce a printable string.

Comment: What is your string??? Did you mean to compress?

Comment: @Manjoor Yes i need some kind of compress

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to shorten an arbitrary string, just as there is no general compression method that works in all cases. So what you need to do is pick a compression method that apples to your expected inputs and use that. Then you just need to convert the results back to a string.

In case you were merely wondering how to convert the results back to a string, there are again any number of ways. Base64 is easy and works well enough. However, it has a 25% overhead compared to a pure binary encoded string.

Comment: Actually, I believe [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) has ~33% overhead.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The overhead is 33% of the original string and 25% of the encoded string.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this answers your intended question. There is a library, [smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) which compresses short English strings efficiently. Perhaps luckily for you, it actually *encodes* the string. If your strings aren't English, the general method used by smaz (a static dictionary) can be used with other compressors.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This library may be suitable for my case. But the implementation is in C. I am searching for a Java and/or c# implementation.

Comment: @KeshanDeSilva It's a very small program, you should be able to convert it by hand pretty easily. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

See "[English Text compression test](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/text.php)". In the article you will find almost all possible algorithms to compress an english text. May be some of them could satisfy your requirements.